# Plotting 2D Schrodinger equation on Python and be able to see a resonance at certain energy

Tags: python, physics, quantum-computing

[image]I have a code to make about the 2D schrodinger equation time dependant. I was able to figure how to use the finites differences and I guess I was able to solve the 1D schrodinger equation. But know I have to plot my wave function in spherical coordinate (so in 2D?) and create an animation to observe a wave packet at certain energies (3.48 Hartree). It is suggested that E=k^2/2 So I used this to make my schrodinger equation energy dependant. The potential and deltak are given. I also need to make the wave packet propagatinf from r=15 to r=0, I think that I just need to insert a minus in my exponential in my psi0 which I did in the code below. Any idea or even explanation would be welcome

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython import display
```

```
dx    = 0.02                      # spatial separation
a= 15
x     = np.arange(0.1, a, dx)       # spatial grid points

deltak = 0.2                       # center of initial gaussian wave-packet

E=3.48
x0= 2

             
A=1.0 / (deltak * np.sqrt(np.pi)) # normalization constant    


hbar = 1 


dt = 0.1  # time interval for snapshots
t0 = 0.0    # initial time
tf = 1.0    # final time

t_eval = np.arange(t0, tf, dt)
k =  np.sqrt(2 * E)

Vx=  7.5 * x**2 * np.exp(-x)

def psi_t2(t,psi):
    return  (-1j * (((-0.5 * D2.dot(psi)) + V * psi)))

# Initial Wavefunction
psi0_ = np.sqrt(A) * np.exp(-(x-x0)**2 / (2.0 * deltak**2)) * np.exp(1j * -k * x) 

# Solve the Initial Value Problem
sol_ = integrate.solve_ivp(psi_t2, t_span = [t0, tf], y0 = psi0_, t_eval = t_eval,method="RK23")

for i,t in enumerate (sol_.t):
    plt.plot(x, np.abs(sol_.y[:,i])**2)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.subplot(1,1,1)
#fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))           

ax.set_xlim(-5, 16)
ax.set_ylim(0, 5)
title = ax.set_title('')


line1, = ax.plot([], [], "k--")  
line2, = ax.plot([], []) 
 
def init():
    line1.set_data(x, V)
    return line1,

def animate(i):
    line2.set_data(x, np.abs(sol_.y[:,i])**2)
    #line2.set_data(x, np.real(sol.y[:, i]))
    #line2.set_data(x, np.abs(psi))
    title.set_text('Time = {0:1.3f}'.format(sol_.t[i])) #permet d'afficher le temps 
    return line1,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,frames=len(sol_.t), interval=50, blit=True)

video = anim.to_html5_video()
html = display.HTML(video)
display.display(html)
plt.close()
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The energy doesn't have an influence on my wave packet which is weird. When I change the energy I see no change. I think that I have probably forgot a k in one of my formula but I can not see where.

Comment: You HAVE to put it into the question with all evidence you produce. I mean, if I'm willing to check, what am I supposed to check? Please produce minimum example of what's wrong

Comment: I uploaded an image of the animation that I have. The problem is the amplitude: it is very small and as I said when I change the energy nothing changes, I can see a resonance everytime which should not be the case.